# Attach multiple image in email from asset in android

Tags: android

I want attach multiple image from asset folder. Email send success full but not getting attached images. show images in email 0 kb.
    My code here. please give any idea. other any way to send multiple images.

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        emailIntent.setType("jpeg/image");
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
        emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);


        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        //convert from paths to Android friendly Parcelable Uri's
        for (int i=0; i < arrImageslist.size(); i++)
        {
            Uri u=Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/DiseaseImages/"+arrImageslist.get(i)); 
            uris.add(u);


        }

        emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Comment: Just try to put those images on sdcard then attached to email intent and see what happen?

Comment: I have images in asset folder. I want send images from asset folder.

Comment: May be those images is un readable for android Email application because of its in asset directory and asset is private for android application.

Comment: Any alternative solution for my problem?

Comment: copy images from /asset to /data/data/<package_neme> directory in MODE_WORLD_READABLE then attache from that path..

Comment: if you get success then please inform me..

Answer (score 1):

The first part....

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.setType("plain/text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"abc@gmail.com"});
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Accident Capture");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, emailBody);

ArrayList<Uri> uriList = getUriListForImages();
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uriList);
Log.d(TAG, "Size of the ArrayList :: " +uriList.size());
FormHolderActivity.this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));
```

------------------GetUriListForImages--------------------------------

```
private ArrayList<Uri> getUriListForImages() throws Exception {
            ArrayList<Uri> myList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            String imageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/folder/";
            File imageDirectory = new File(imageDirectoryPath);
            String[] fileList = imageDirectory.list();
            if(fileList.length != 0) {
                for(int i=0; i<fileList.length; i++)
                {   
                    try 
                    {   
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(7);
                        values.put(Images.Media.TITLE, fileList[i]);
                        values.put(Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileList[i]);
                        values.put(Images.Media.DATE_TAKEN, new Date().getTime());
                        values.put(Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg");
                        values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_ID, imageDirectoryPath.hashCode());
                        values.put(Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME, fileList[i]);
                        values.put("_data", imageDirectoryPath + fileList[i]);
                        ContentResolver contentResolver = getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
                        Uri uri = contentResolver.insert(Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
                        myList.add(uri);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
            return myList;
        }
```